# Может ли Yandex.Tank нарисовать график instances во время rps теста?

Tags: яндекс-танк, нагрузочное-тестирование

Может ли Yandex.Tank нарисовать в репорте график количества *active instances* во время *rps_schedule* теста?

Текущий конфиг:

```
[phantom]
rps_schedule=line(1,20,5m)
ammofile=ammo.txt
[tank]
plugin_web=yatank_OnlineReport
```

Comment: А какой репорт вы имеете в виду? Плагин? И какой пушкой стреляете?

Comment: @Direvius добавил конфиг в вопрос.

Comment: Report плагин как раз сейчас полностью переделываю под новую ветку танка (1.8), сделаю там эти графики. Старый плагин не может.

Comment: @Direvius Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Мы сделали публичный бесплатный сервис для анализа результатов стрельб Танком -- [Overload](http://yandextank.readthedocs.io/en/latest/core_and_modules.html#yandex-overload). Он вам все нарисует. Пример [тут](https://overload.yandex.net/487#tab=test_data), смотрите график Threads.